# How do you correctly convert from a local time as a string to a utc unixtp and back in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm after a c++20 option for this, but it must be an MSVC compiler compatible solution

I would have thought this was pretty simple to find a couple of years after the new chroni library has been introduced, but I can't find a clean example.
I'm trying to modernise a horrific bodge of old c++ date/time code converting to and from string and unix timestamp

___ EDIT ___

Requirements are:-

1. accepts all three parameters as runtime arguments
2. correctly handles time prior to 1970 (to the limit of -int64 seconds)

The following is an update based on Howard Hinnant's suggestion. However currently the functions fail at std::format or parse

```
// formats = "%d/%m/%Y", "%Y%m%d%H%M", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%", etc     https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter#Format_specification
//                                                                  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification
// locality = "Europe/London" NOT "en_GB.utf8"              https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
std::string utp642Str(std::int64_t utp64, std::string formats, std::string locality)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    sys_seconds tp_utc{ seconds{utp64} };
    auto tp = locate_zone(locality)->to_local(tp_utc);
//  std::string str = std::vformat(formats, tp);            // vformat doesn't accept a timepoint
    std::string str = std::format("{0:%d/%m/%Y} {0:%H:%M:%S}", tp);
    return str;
}

std::int64_t str2utp64(std::string date_str, std::string formats, std::string locality)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    istringstream in{ std::move(date_str) };
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    local_seconds tp;
    in >> parse(formats, tp);
    auto tp_utc = locate_zone(locality)->to_sys(tp);
    int64_t utp64 = tp_utc.time_since_epoch().count();
    return utp64;

}
```

___ END EDIT ___

even at the first easiest step I have a challange - I have the following function to output a simple count of the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.

```
int64_t timeNow() {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

Attempting to verify the output online I find numerous different outputs - all claiming to report utc and all different - so is even these sites are not correctly setting their clocks (presumably there is a standard website doing this somewhere - so bonus for suggesting recommending this)?
https://www.unixtimestamp.com/
https://unixtime.org/
https://www.epochconverter.com/

However the primary goal is to convert an input string for a specific locale (eg British time) to a utc, then (at some future point) recover it to a string in the same locale.

Dates are within current human lifespans - which means they could go back to the early 1900s
There is a ton of internal code I'm interfacing with which uses negative values to count backwards from 1/1/1970 - and that would be too complex to change so the output should also report the number of seconds before the epoch for dates prior 1/1/1970.

So I'm after suggestions for clean modern code options to achieve this...

Using the test function I'm currently getting this - which is at least internally consistent - even if I don't know if it is "true" as verified against external websites

```
// Output from testTimeDateFunctions();
Now: 1690624728
Default format = "%d/%m/%Y"
Now0: 29/07/2023
Now1: 2023 Jul
Now2: 29 Jul 2023 10:58:48
Now3: 29 Jul 2023 10:58:48
Now3: 29 Jul 2023 10:58:48
Won0: 29 Jul 2023 10:58:48
Default format = "%d %b %Y"
Won0: 1690588800 = 29/07/2023
Won0: 1690588800 = 29/07/2023
Won2: 1690628328
Won3: 1690628328
old: 13/07/1920 07:37:05
old: -1
old: -1
old: -1
dlo0: 31/12/1969
dlo1: 31/12/1969 23:59:59.0000000
dlo2: 31/12/1969 23:59:59.0000000
dlo3: 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59.0000000
dlo_old0: 13/07/1920
dlo_old1: 13/07/1920 07:37:05.0000000
dlo_old3: 13 Jul 1920 07:37:05.0000000
```

```
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter#Format_specification
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification
// default format = "%d/%m/%Y",                 //eg "%Y%m%d%H%M", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%"
std::string unixTP2StrOld(int64_t timePoint, std::string format = "%d/%m/%Y");
std::string unixTP2StrOld(int64_t utp64, std::string format) {

    // needs converting to correctly output localised time
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t((time_t)utp64);

    std::string s;


    //  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::utc_clock> epoch;
    //  std::cout << std::format("The time of the Unix epoch was {0:%F}T{0:%R%z}.", epoch);


        //  std::string s = std::format("{:%Y%m%d%H%M}", timePoint);

    //  std::string_view  fmt = "{0:" + format + "}";
    //  std::string s = std::vformat(fmt, timePoint);

    //  s = std::format(std::runtime_format(fmt), timePoint);


    if (format == "%d/%m/%Y")
        s = std::format("{0:%d/%m/%Y}", timePoint);         // long form year
    else if (format == "%d/%m/%y")
        s = std::format("{0:%d/%m/%y}", timePoint);         // short form year
    else if (format == "%H:%M:%S")
        s = std::format("{0:%T}", timePoint);
    else if (format == "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        s = std::format("{0:%d/%m/%Y} {0:%H:%M:%S}", timePoint);
    else if (format == "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        s = std::format("{0:%d %b %Y} {0:%H:%M:%S}", timePoint);
    else if (format == "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
        s = std::format("{0:%Y_%m_%d}_{0:%H_%M_%S}", timePoint);
    else if (format == "%b %y")
        s = std::format("{0:%b %y}", timePoint);
    else if (format == "%d %b %Y")
        s = std::format("{0:%d %b %Y}", timePoint);


    else
    {

        std::cout << "Using old format unixTP: \"" << utp64 << ": " << format << "\"\n";

        //  return std::format("{:" + format + "}", timePoint);
        //  return std::format(("{:" + format + "}").c_str(), timePoint);
        //return s;


        if (utp64 == INT64_MIN or utp64 == INT64_MAX)
            return "date undef";

        std::chrono::year_month_day ymd = unixTP2YMD(utp64);
        //std::chrono::hh_mm_ss time = unixTP2HMS(utp64);
        std::basic_stringstream<char> tpDay;
        std::basic_stringstream<char> tpMonth;
        std::basic_stringstream<char> tpYear;



        // Add padding 0 if day is under 10
        if (ymd.day() > (std::chrono::day)9) {
            tpDay << (unsigned)ymd.day();
        }
        else {
            tpDay << "0" << (unsigned)ymd.day();
        }

        // Add padding 0 if month is under 10
        if (ymd.month() > (std::chrono::month)9) {
            tpMonth << (unsigned)ymd.month();
        }
        else {
            tpMonth << "0" << (unsigned)ymd.month();
        }


        if (format.find("%y") != std::string::npos) {
            // If format is for short year then add padding 0 if year is under 10
            int yr = (int)ymd.year() - 2000;
            if (yr < 10)
                tpYear << "0" << yr;
            else
                tpYear << yr;
        }
        else
            tpYear << (int)ymd.year();



        replaceOnce(format, "%d", tpDay.str());
        replaceOnce(format, "%b", real2BriefMonth((unsigned)ymd.month()));
        replaceOnce(format, "%m", tpMonth.str());
        replaceOnce(format, "%y", tpYear.str());
        replaceOnce(format, "%Y", tpYear.str());

        return format;
    }

    return s;

}
// convert a date/time string to a 64 bit signed int which reflects the number of seconds relative to the unix timepoint epoch
// format egs  "%d %b %Y"(=default)  "%Y-%m-%d"  "%d/%m/%Y"  "%d %b %Y %H:%M"
int64_t str2utp64old(std::string eventDate, std::string format = "%d %b %Y");
int64_t str2utp64old(std::string eventDate, std::string format) {

    auto timePoint = str2TimePoint(eventDate, format);
    int64_t utp64 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(timePoint.time_since_epoch()).count();

    if (utp64 == 0) {
        if (eventDate != "" and eventDate != "01 Jan 1970 00:00:00" and eventDate != "01 Jan 1970" and eventDate != "01/01/1970" and !(eventDate.substr(0, 11) == "01 Jan 1970" and format == "%d %b %Y"))
            std::cout << "WARNING: eventDate is: " << eventDate << " but str2utp64 returning 0 - this can occur if function call doesn't correctly specify the date format\n";
    }

    return utp64;
}

// This function will convert a time since unix timepoint epoch (ie ~1/1/1970) into a date string in a specified format and localization
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter#Format_specification
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification
// Example usage of the function
// std::cout << unixTP2Str(1626108620, "%A %c", "en_GB.utf8") << std::endl;

// default format = "%d/%m/%Y",                 //eg "%Y%m%d%H%M", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%"
std::string unixTP2Str(int64_t utp64, std::string format, std::string locality) {

    if (utp64 < 0)
        return unixTP2StrOld(utp64, format);

    if (utp64 == INT64_MIN)
        return "NULL";      // If the timestamp is INT64_MIN, return NULL

    std::locale localisation = std::locale(locality);
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(utp64);// Convert UNIX timestamp into a system_clock::time_point

    time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);       // Create a time_t object from the time_point

    // check if localtime returns a null pointer
    struct tm* loc_tm = localtime(&tt);
    if (!loc_tm) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: unixTP2Str: " << utp64 << " " << format << " " << locality << ". (Switching to unixTP2StrOld)\n";
        return unixTP2StrOld(utp64, format);
    }

    std::ostringstream oss;                                     // Create an output string stream to format the time
    oss.imbue(localisation);                                    // Set the locale

    // Use strftime to format the time into the string stream
    char buff[100];
    try {
        strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), format.c_str(), loc_tm);
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: unixTP2Str: " << utp64 << " " << format << " " << locality << ". (Switching to unixTP2StrOld)\n";
        return unixTP2StrOld(utp64, format);
    }
    oss << buff;

    return oss.str();           // Return the formatted time string
}


// This function will convert a date/time string in a specified format and localization into a UNIX timestamp
// Example usage of the function
// std::cout << str2utp64("Tuesday Jul 13 07:37:00 2021", "%A %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", "en_GB.utf8") << std::endl;
int64_t str2utp64(std::string date_str, std::string format, std::string locality) {

    std::locale localisation = std::locale(locality);

    std::istringstream iss(date_str);                           // Create a time stream from the input string
    iss.imbue(localisation);                                    // Set the locale
    std::tm parsed_tm = {};                                     // Create a struct tm to hold the parsed date/time
    iss >> std::get_time(&parsed_tm, format.c_str());           // Parse the date/time from the string stream

    time_t tt = mktime(&parsed_tm);                                                                         // Convert the struct tm into a time_t
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(tt);                  // Convert the time_t into a system_clock::time_point
    int64_t utp64 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count();        // Convert the system_clock::time_point into a UNIX timestamp

    if (utp64 == -1)
        return str2utp64old(date_str, format);

    return utp64;               // Return the UNIX timestamp
}


void testTimeDateFunctions() {

    int64_t now = timeNow();

    std::cout << "Now: " << now << "\n";
    std::cout << "Default format = \"%d/%m/%Y\"\n";
    std::cout << "Now0: " << unixTP2Str(now) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Now1: " << unixTP2Str(now, "%Y %b") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Now2: " << unixTP2Str(now, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Now3: " << unixTP2Str(now, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", "en_GB.utf8") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Now3: " << unixTP2Str(now, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", "en_GB.utf8") << "\n";

    std::string nowStr = unixTP2Str(now, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S");

    std::cout << "Won0: " << nowStr << "\n";
    std::cout << "Default format = \"%d %b %Y\"\n";
    std::cout << "Won0: " << str2utp64(nowStr) << " = " << unixTP2Str(str2utp64(nowStr)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Won0: " << str2utp64(nowStr.substr(0, 11)) << " = " << unixTP2Str(str2utp64(nowStr.substr(0, 11))) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Won2: " << str2utp64(nowStr, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Won3: " << str2utp64(nowStr, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", "en_GB.utf8") << "\n";


    std::string oldDate = "13/07/1920 07:37:05";
    std::cout << "old: " << oldDate << "\n";
    std::cout << "old: " << str2utp64(oldDate, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") << "\n";
    std::cout << "old: " << str2utp64(oldDate, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "en_GB.utf8") << "\n";

    int64_t old = str2utp64(oldDate, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S");
    std::cout << "old: " << old << "\n";
    std::cout << "dlo0: " << unixTP2Str(old) << "\n";
    std::cout << "dlo1: " << unixTP2Str(old, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") << "\n";
    std::cout << "dlo2: " << unixTP2Str(old, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "en_GB.utf8") << "\n";
    std::cout << "dlo3: " << unixTP2Str(old, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", "en_GB.utf8") << "\n";

    int64_t old_old = str2utp64old(oldDate, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S");
    std::cout << "dlo_old0: " << unixTP2StrOld(old_old) << "\n";
    std::cout << "dlo_old1: " << unixTP2StrOld(old_old, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") << "\n";
    std::cout << "dlo_old3: " << unixTP2StrOld(old_old, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Just a couple of comments: 1. Use `std::chrono::floor` in place of `std::chrono::duration_cast` to get a consistent "round down" behavior for time points prior to the Unix epoch. 2. `"{0:" + format + "}"` should work just fine. Catch the result in a `std::string` to ensure you don't have dangling reference problems. 3. You can send a `std::locale` as the first argument to the format functions. 4. There's probably 3 or more questions in here. Consider asking a very focused question with a small piece of code, like: Here's one specific thing that isn't working the way I thought it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer *only* the question in the title:

> How do you correctly convert from a local time as a string to a utc unixtp and back in c++20?

First the code, then a line-by-line explanation follows:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string_view>

constexpr std::string_view fmt = "%d/%m/%Y %T";

std::string
Unix2London(std::int64_t i)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    sys_seconds tp_utc{seconds{i}};
    auto tp = locate_zone("Europe/London")->to_local(tp_utc);
    return vformat("{:" + string(fmt) + "}", make_format_args(tp));
}

std::int64_t
London2Unix(std::string s)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    istringstream in{std::move(s)};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    local_seconds tp;
    in >> parse(string(fmt), tp);
    auto tp_utc = locate_zone("Europe/London")->to_sys(tp);
    return tp_utc.time_since_epoch().count();
}

int
main()
{
    auto ut = London2Unix("29/07/2023 11:45:20");
    std::cout << ut << '\n';
    auto s = Unix2London(ut);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1690627520
29/07/2023 11:45:20
```

[Demo.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qfjqs4vqM)

I'm using the time zone "Europe/London" as this was mentioned in the question:

> (eg British time)

But any IANA time zone name could be used.  Or the computer's locally set time zone could be used by using `current_zone()` in place of `locate_zone`.

**Unix2London**

First convert the integral number of seconds to `std::chrono::seconds` and then convert that into a `time_point<system_clock, seconds>` which has a handy type alias called `sys_seconds`.

Next get the desired time zone and use the member function `to_local` to convert the Unix time point into a local time point of the same precision.

Finally format the local time point into a string using whatever formatting you prefer.

**London2Unix**

Move the string into a `istringstream`.  I like to use exceptions for handling parse errors, but if you prefer not to, then skip setting `ios::failbit`.  You can instead manually check `in.fail()` for parse errors.

Next parse into a local time point.  I'm using seconds precision, but use any precision you want.  E.g. `local_time<milliseconds>`.

parse using the preferred format.

Then using the desired time_zone use the member function `to_sys` to change the local time into a `time_point` based on `system_clock`.  The result is a Unix time point with the same precision as the local time point.

Finally convert the `time_point` into an integral type.

Comment: Thanks. That visually looks like what I was imagining, but when I add the additional parameters it doesn't work. std::format is compile-time only but std::vformat won't accept a timepoint and parse also failing.
The reason for the rambly question without a "this is faulty" point is that the code I have actually works perfectly - it just looks horrible and I figured there would be a better way.

Comment: I've modified my answer to use `vformat` instead.

Comment: No wonder you're a Time Lord that absolutely nailed it! Thanks